# PBI Desktop automation while Windows screen is locked

Tags: python, windows, automation, powerbi-desktop, pywinauto

I want to refresh my pbix file in PBI Desktop while Windows is locked, on Virtual Machine. However I am not even able to click on Help button.

```
wb = "C:\\test.pbix"
os.system('start "" "' + wb + '"')
time.sleep(10)
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path="PBIDesktop.exe")
win = app.window(title_re='.*Power BI Desktop')
win.wait("visible", timeout=20)

# way 1 .click_input()
win['Help'].click_input() #not working if screen is locked, when unlocked all is working well
# way 2 .click_input()
win.Help.click_input() #not working if screen is locked, when unlocked all is working well
# way 1 .click()
win['Help'].click() #not working at all
# way 2 .click()
win.Help.click() #not working at all
```

[image]

For other job I am using a similar pywinauto approach to interact with File Picker with Edge while screen is locked and all is working well:

```
w_open_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Open', class_name='#32770')[0]
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(title_re="webpage*")
w_open = app.window(handle=w_open_handle)
w_open.Edit.set_edit_text(pth)
```

However there are different backends 'uia' vs. 'win32'....

I have to go via PBI desktop app and to make refresh and publish there. If pywinauto is not way for me are there any other ways to do so? e.g. 3DS Max has scripting interface which enables interacting with program without gui.
Thx

Comment: I'd recommend to carefully read this guide first: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html